# How to pass a firestore document reference for a collection made in MainActivity to a child fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a FragmentPagerAdapter in my MainActivity.java, and the Fragment Manager defined here renders the ViewPager for 3 fragments-- one of them is MapActivity.java. I have created a collection in Firebase (Cloud Firestore) named "users" and added documents corresponding to each userid in the Main Activity, using FirebaseUserAuth.getCurrentUser().getuid(). Each document has 4 fields, one of them being "Coordinates". In the MAp Activity fragment, I want to update only the "Coordinates" field for that user's document only. (this field is of 'Geopoint' type).

I tried passing the corresponding user's document reference by setting bundle arguments as shown below, but that didn't work. Please help, any hint/suggestion would be appreciated.
My Main Activity section:

```
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            //final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    if (user != null) {
                        uid=auth.getUid();
                        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                                .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                                .build();
                        db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
    //initialising document with some sample data
                        Map<String, Object> users = new HashMap<>();
                        LatLng gp=new LatLng(22,88);
                        users.put("Coordinates", gp);
                        users.put("Crowd volume", 20);
                        users.put("Timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                        users.put("Userid", uid);
                        db.collection("Location Data")
                                .add(users)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                                        //Bundle args=new Bundle();
                                        //args.putString("docref",documentReference.toString());
                                        //frag.setArguments(args);
//this above part doesn't seem to work
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                                    }
                                });
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
```

In my Map Activity, I did this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        GeoPoint gp=new GeoPoint(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude());

        //Bundle bundle=getArguments();---this didn't work
        db.collection("Location Data").document("docref".getId()) //need help here, what do I write in place of docref?
                .update(gp)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
you could use intents to move the id between activities or you could save all your id's and DocumentReference objects in a map in a different class as a static variable.

Long answer:
I passed the id as a String using `putExtraString()` and `getExtraString()` on the intent.

So:
In your MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("documentID",documentReference.getId())
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your LoginActivity:

Instead of `"docref".getId()` just use `getIntent().getStringExtra("documentID")`.

This is not the perfect solution you might want to consider storing them in a different class as a static Map variable (that way you literally keep the objects) or perhaps store them in an offline database like [room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)